# How to fill advanced return management datas fields during bapi call

Tags: abap, sap-erp

We want to fill the fields for advanced return management (struct. MSR_S_SALES_ITEM) in the return order (like in transaction va02) during the call of function module BAPI_CUSTOMERRETURN_CREATE or afterwards.
Can somebody tell us, how we can fill them (example "Customer Inspection Code, CUST_INSP_CODE"). We found the class CL_MSR_SALES, but have no clue how to use it, because there is no documentation.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the sap note 2488803. It includes a new function module "SD_ADV_RETURNS_CREATE". With this you can create a return order with advanced return management datas.

Hopefully it helps someone else.